# How to convert java double into 2 decimal value

Tags: java

Question 1:

Assume `Double d = 10.233444`. I want to convert and put result into same double, so that my value should be `d= 10.23`;

Question 2:

Assume `Double d = 10.235444`. I want to convert and put result into same double, so that my value should be `d= 10.24`;

How to do this in java?

Comment: That is not even rounding up the values. It is to get the fractional part's first three values and then rounding them up.

Comment: my question is related to rounding up the values. updated the question. check it now

Comment: Now makes sense, before it was just `d = 24`. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roundoff value

```
Double d = 10.233444;

double roundOff = Math.round(d * 100.0) / 100.0;
System.out.println(roundOff);
// Output is 10.24

Double d2 = 10.235444;

roundOff = Math.round(d2 * 100.0) / 100.0;
System.out.println(roundOff);
// Output is 10.25
```

Comment: Why multiply by 100 then divide by 100?